# Min-width causes an extra space vertically on Android screen in portrait mode in HTML/CSS

Tags: android, html, css

Recently, I met an issue with Android Chrome browser, in portrait mode only (in landscape looks fine) when using the following HTML code and CSS code.

I use bootstrap framework

```css
body {

  min-width: 900px;

}

#test div {

  max-height: 400px;

  overflow: auto;

}

#test table {

  margin-bottom: 0;

}

#test table tr td {

  width: 25%;

  padding-right: 5px;

}

#test table tr th {

  width: 25%;

}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1" id="test">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Modification</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>

  <div>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdad asdadsasdas</td>
          <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
          <td>asdasd asd asd</td>
          <td>adsasd adsasdasd</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Or better, a jsfiddle document: http://jsfiddle.net/32Lg9ddf/

Now, please simulate it in **Android device in portrait mode** and you'll see that will appear an extra space (height is bigger but is not visible in Inspect Element in Chrome) at the bottom of page when scrolling.

That's strange because on other devices with iOS and Windows Phone it looks very good and no extra space (or bigger height) is shown.

See my screen recording to see the problem: http://i.imgur.com/Q0oAvT2.gif  I used remote debugging using Nexus 7 tablet with 7" screen.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: The issue lies in your use of min-width and max-width.
Arrgh. Sorry. Hit enter too early. =D

Comment: I want to use `min-width` but how to solve the issue met in Android without removing `min-width` property...?

Comment: By giving your body a minimum width of 900px it won't scale down when the viewport is too narrow.
The div though will scale down as it has a max-height of 400px.

Answer (score 1):

How do you want it to display on smaller screen sizes than 900px? 
You can handle that using responsive css with media queries,  there are many examples online.

For example, when a screensize is 600 to 900px it could reduce the font size or alter the `min-width` (and possibly increase the max-height).  You can also apply the `min-width` of 900px only to larger screen sizes and use `width:auto` for the rest.

Setting the [overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)  property to 'scroll' in CSS  will show a horizontal scrollbar instead of the extra space underneath, but only when the screen size used is too small. `overflow` set to hidden will just cut out anything that does not fit without giving extra space underneath (if the data is fixed and always fits in you can use this or reduce the min-width size).

This can be done adding this to you CSS file:

```
body { overflow:scroll;}
```

this will scroll horizontally and/or vertically. Alternatively you can apply this to the `table` tag.

Responsive HTML examples, including **bootstrap** which is the most popular tool for handling this for you. 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp